# Using mypy's generic self with python2 type comments

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, mypy, type-hinting

I have a case where I would like to use a [generic self](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self) for typing with mypy. However I need to maintain python 2.7 compatibility, so I'm using the type comment syntax.

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='Shape')

class Shape:
    def set_scale(self: T, scale: float) -> T:
        self.scale = scale
        return self
```

How do I translate this code to a type comment? Type comments omit the 'self' type, so the `T` definition gets lost:

```
    def set_scale(self, scale):
        # type: (float) -> T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* to exclude `self`; you simply have the option to do so:

> When using the short form (e.g. # type: (str, int) -> None) every argument must be accounted for, except the first argument of instance and class methods (**those are usually omitted, but it's allowed to include them**).
>
> ---
>
> From PEP-484, third note at the end of [Suggested Syntax for Python 2.7 and straddling code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code)

So you can write

```
def set_scale(self, scale):
    # type: (T, float) -> T
```

It's the job of the consumer of such a comment to count parameters and determine if `self` was omitted or not.

Comment: Perfect! I should have thought to try that.